# Adding a model to each table of an array of tables but only populates the last table in the iteration

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom made (excel like) table headers. Each header includes 2 labels, a column name and and an icon that when pressed opens a filter panel. each filter panel should have a table with two column. one a Boolean type and other one holds all the values from the column to be filtered. Hhow the filter looks:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyMZA.png]

When the program runs it creates 13 layered filtering panels. the table in the panels should be populate each with their table model but only the last table gets populated. The first 12 table have the right number of rows but  the are empty. Can anyone help me understand what is it that i am doing wrong?
 How the panels are displayed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffj7x.png]

```
public CustomTable(String sQLTableName,int sqlColumnCount, String[] sQLColumns,String[] sqlLabelNames,String whereClause) {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1600, 800);
    this.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel = new JLayeredPane();
    this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    totalPanel= new JPanel();totalPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,30,5));
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //setContentPane(mainPanel);
    scroll= new JScrollPane();scroll.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    obtainMetadataInfo(sQLTableName,sqlColumnCount, sQLColumns, sqlLabelNames, whereClause);
    setMaintable(createInternalTable());
    getMaintable().getColumnModel().addColumnModelListener(this);   
    panelFilter = createFilterPanel();
    scroll.setViewportView(getMaintable());
    mainPanel.add(scroll);
    columnMarginChanged(new ChangeEvent(getMaintable().getColumnModel()));
    mainPanel.add(panelFilter, BorderLayout.NORTH);mainPanel.add(totalPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);    
    totalMinsTxt = new JTextField("£ 10000.00");totalLabourCostTxt= new JTextField("£ 10000.00"); totalMaterialCostTxt = new JTextField("£ 10000.00"); totalCostTxt = new JTextField("£ 10000.00");
    totalMinsLb=new JLabel("Total Minutes");totalLabourCostLb= new JLabel("Total Labour Cost");totalMaterialCostLb= new JLabel("Total Material Cost");totalCostLb = new JLabel("Total Cost");
    totalPanel.add(totalMinsLb);totalPanel.add(totalMinsTxt);
    totalPanel.add(totalLabourCostLb);totalPanel.add(totalLabourCostTxt);
    totalPanel.add(totalMaterialCostLb);totalPanel.add(totalMaterialCostTxt);
    totalPanel.add(totalCostLb);totalPanel.add(totalCostTxt);
}
public JPanel createFilterPanel(){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // Panel to hold all the Column Header labels
            panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
            Font font = new Font("New Times Romen", Font.BOLD, 12);

            filterPanels =new Box[SQLTableImport.getColumnCount()];// containers to hold the name of the column and the filter icon
            filterText = new JLabel[SQLTableImport.getColumnCount()];// an array to hold the column header labels
            filterIcons =new JLabel[SQLTableImport.getColumnCount()]; //an array to hold the  filter icons
            models =new DefaultTableModel[SQLTableImport.getColumnCount()];// an array to hold the table models to be added to each table in the filter panel
            allFilterPanels = new FilterPanel[SQLTableImport.getColumnCount()]; // an array to hold the object of the FilterPanel class

            for(int i = 0;i<SQLTableImport.getColumnCount();i++){  
                filterPanels[i] =  Box.createHorizontalBox(); // create one container for each number of SQL columns
                filterText[i] = new JLabel(SQLTableImport.getColumnNames()[i]); // create a label for each number of SQL columns to hold the column name
                filterText[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                filterIcons[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Icons.EXPAND));// create a label for each number of SQL columns to hold the expand icons

                setColumnIndex(i); 
                SQLTableImport.setSqlSelectedType(SQLTableImport.getSqlColumnType()[getColumnIndex()]); // set the SQL object type
                SQLTableImport.setSqlColumnName(SQLTableImport.getSqlColumnNames()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()]); // set the SQL column  name
                FilterPanel.setTableColumnName(SQLTableImport.getColumnNames()[getColumnIndex()]);// set the SQL lable column  name

                String iconDescriptionColumn ="CASE WHEN non_conformances.Status='Complete' THEN (select Name from `icons` where ID='1' )WHEN `Deadline`> DATE(NOW()) and `Status`<>'Complete' THEN (select Name from `icons`"
                        + " where ID='3')ELSE (select Name from `icons` where ID='2')END "; 

                model = new SQLTableImport(iconDescriptionColumn).getFilterModelFromSqlTable(); // model to be added in the filter table

                models[i] = model; //add all the model in an array


                allFilterPanels[i]= new FilterPanel(SQLTableImport.getSqlColumnType()[i]); 
                //((AbstractTableModel) allFilterPanels[i].getTableSearch().getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
                mainPanel.add(allFilterPanels[i]);
                mainPanel.setLayer(allFilterPanels[i],new Integer(i),0);
                allFilterPanels[i].setVisible(false);


                filterIcons[i].setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));filterIcons[i].setOpaque(true);filterIcons[i].setBackground(SystemColor.menu);

                final int index=i;
                filterPanels[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        filterPanels[index].setOpaque(true);
                        filterPanels[index].setBackground(new Color(51,98,140));
                        filterText[index].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        filterPanels[index].setOpaque(true);
                        filterPanels[index].setBackground(new Color(214,217,223));
                        filterText[index].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


                        setFiltersInvisible(allFilterPanels);
                        filterIcons[index].setOpaque(true);
                        if(isSort){  //**************************************** create a map with index and true/false values to change the icons properly*******************
                            getMaintable().setModel(getMainModel().sortMainTable("ASC"));
                            filterIcons[index].setIcon(new ImageIcon(Icons.SELECTED_EXPAND));
                            isSort = false;

                        }
                        else{
                            getMaintable().setModel(getMainModel().sortMainTable("DESC"));
                            filterIcons[index].setIcon(new ImageIcon(Icons.EXPAND));
                            isSort = true;
                        }


                    }


                });

                filterIcons[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {     

                        filterIcons[index].setOpaque(true);
                        filterIcons[index].setBackground(new Color(51,98,140));

                        setxCoordonateOnScreen(filterPanels[index].getX()+filterPanels[index].getWidth()-250); //set the x coordinate where the filter frame will be positioned
                        setyCoordonateOnScreen(filterPanels[index].getY()+(filterPanels[index].getHeight()*2)-2);
                        setTableWidth(panel.getWidth());
                        allFilterPanels[index].setVisible(true);
                        allFilterPanels[index].setLocation(getxCoordonateOnScreen(), getyCoordonateOnScreen());

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        filterIcons[index].setOpaque(true);
                        filterIcons[index].setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
                    }

                });
                filterText[i].setFont(font);
                filterPanels[i].add(filterText[i]);
                filterPanels[i].add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
                filterPanels[i].add(filterIcons[i]);
                panel.add(filterPanels[i]);

            }


            return panel;
        }
public class FilterPanel extends JPanel{
    public FilterPanel(String sqlType) {
    if(sqlType.equals("DATE")){ // if the column type is date it creates a specific panel for filtering dates
        createBasicFrame(); //create the frame, set the Content Pane,set the background colour, set the GridBagLayout, sets the close button
        addDatePanelComponents(); // create the panel and add all the components for date frame
        addBasicComponents();
        adjustBasicComponents();
        adjustDatePanel();
    }
    else if(sqlType.equals("BLOB")|| sqlType.equals("TINYINT")){// creates a specific panel for filtering icons and check boxes
        createBasicFrame();
        addBasicComponents();
        addSearchTable();
        adjustBasicComponents();
        adjustSearchTable();
    }
    else{// the default filter panel
        createBasicFrame();
        addBasicComponents();
        adjustBasicComponents();
        addSearchTable();
        addSearchPanel();
        adjustTheSearchPanel();
        adjustSearchTable();
    }
}
    public void addSearchTable( ){
    setTableSearch(new JTable());
    getTableSearch().setModel(CustomTable.models[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()]);// set the model to the search table from the array of models which is obtain from SQLTableImport class
    adjustTable();
    searchScroll = new JScrollPane();
    searchScroll.setViewportView(getTableSearch());
}

public void adjustSearchTable(){
    /////////Third Row////////
    addComp(this, searchScroll, 0, 3, 5,1, 0, 4.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
}
public void adjustBasicComponents(){
    //////First Row//////
    addComp(this, title, 0, 0, 5,1, 1, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(this, closeLabel, 1, 0, 1,1, 1, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    //////////Second Row//////////
    addComp(this, cleareIcon, 0, 1, 1,1, 1, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(this, clearTxt, 1, 1, 1,1, 2, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);
    /////Last Row//////
    addComp(this, cancelBt, 0, 4, 2,1, 1, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.EAST, GridBagConstraints.NONE);
    addComp(this, okBt, 1, 4, 1,1, 1, 0.1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE);

}
    private void addComp(JPanel thePanel, JComponent comp, int xPos, int yPos, int gridW, int gridH,double compWidth,double compHeight, int place, int stretch){
    GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridConstraints.gridx = xPos;// Define the x position of the component
    gridConstraints.gridy = yPos;// Define the y position of the component
    gridConstraints.gridwidth = gridW;// Number of columns the component takes up
    gridConstraints.gridheight = gridH;// Number of rows the component takes up
    gridConstraints.weightx = compWidth;// Gives the layout manager a hint on how to adjust component width (0 equals fixed)
    gridConstraints.weighty = compHeight;// Gives the layout manager a hint on how to adjust component height (0 equals fixed)
    gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);// Defines padding top, left, bottom, right
    gridConstraints.anchor = place;// Defines where to place components if they don't fill the space: CENTER, NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST NORTHEAST, etc.
    gridConstraints.fill = stretch;// How should the component be stretched to fill the space: NONE, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, BOTH
    thePanel.add(comp, gridConstraints);
}
```

}

```
public class SQLTableImport {
    //***********Constructor for Filter Table export (2 columns Check box and string)**********
public SQLTableImport(String descriptionColumn){
    if(getSqlSelectedType().equals("BLOB")){
        setSql("SELECT DISTINCT "+getSqlColumnName()+" , "+descriptionColumn+" FROM `"+ getTableName() +"`"+whereClause+"");
    }
    else{
        setSql("SELECT DISTINCT "+getSqlColumnName()+" FROM `"+ getTableName() +"`"+whereClause+"");
    }
}
    //***********METHOD FOR RETURNING THE MODEL FOR A FILTER FRAME 1 COLUMN AND 1 CHECKBOX COLUMN

public DefaultTableModel getFilterModelFromSqlTable(){  
    if(getSqlSelectedType().equals("BLOB")){emptyHeaders= new Object[][]{null,null,null};}
        DefaultTableModel dFilterTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(emptyrows, emptyHeaders){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return column == 0;
        }
            public Class <?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                if(column==0){
                    return Boolean.class;
                }
                if(column==2){
                    return String.class;
                }

                switch (getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()]) {
                    case "VARCHAR":
                        return String.class;
                    case "INT":
                        return Integer.class;
                    case "DECIMAL":
                        return Double.class;
                    case "DATE":
                        return Date.class;
                    case "TINYINT":
                        return String.class;
                    case "BLOB":
                        return Icon.class;
                    default:
                        return Object.class;
                }
                }
        };
                    try {
                        setPst(Utilities.sqlConnnect().prepareStatement(getSql()));
                        setRs(getPst().executeQuery(getSql()));  
                        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData tempResult = getPst().getMetaData();
                        int tempColumnCount = tempResult.getColumnCount();
                        Object[] tempRow= new Object[tempColumnCount+1];


                        while(getRs().next()){
                        // Gets the column values based on class type expected
                            tempRow[0]= false;

                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].equals("VARCHAR")){
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount]= getRs().getString(tempColumnCount);
                                }
                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].equals("INT")){
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount]= getRs().getInt(tempColumnCount);
                                    }
                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].equals("DECIMAL")){
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount]= getRs().getDouble(tempColumnCount);
                                    }
                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].toString().equals("DATE")){

                                    }
                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].equals("TINYINT")){
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount]= getRs().getBoolean(tempColumnCount);
                                    }
                                if(getSqlColumnType()[CustomTable.getColumnIndex()].equals("BLOB")){
                                    Blob blob = getRs().getBlob(tempColumnCount-1);
                                    ImageIcon icon = null;
                                    try (InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream()) {
                                        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
                                        icon = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(17, 17, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
                                    }
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount-1] =icon;
                                    tempRow[tempColumnCount]= getRs().getString(tempColumnCount);

                                    }

                            // Adds the row of data to the end of the model
                                dFilterTableModel.addRow(tempRow);

                                     }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                    }
                    finally {
                        try {
                            getPst().close();
                            getRs().close();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1);
                        }
                    }   
    return dFilterTableModel;}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> When the program runs it creates 13 layered filtering panels. the table in the panels should be populate each with their table model but only the last table gets populated.

```
searchScroll = new JScrollPane();
searchScroll.setViewportView(getTableSearch());
```

I don't see where you ever add the scroll pane to a panel.

You can't just create 13 scroll panes without adding each one individually to a panel.

The "searchScroll" variable can only reference the last one created which would my guess why you only see the last table.

Comment: I've included the method that adds all the components to the panel, including the scroll pane. Hope this helps.

Comment: @bogdanbogdanmihoci_86yahoocom, No it doesn't help. I don't have time to read through and understand your code. I've given you a suggestion. It is up to you to understand the suggestion and check your code. So do some debugging. Add System.out.println() statements to make sure the code executes as you expect and that each time you create a scrollpane you add it to a unique panel.

Comment: My first experience posting a question on this website and i get 'I don't have time to read through and understand your code'. If you had a look at the pictures you could have seen that all 13 panels have 13 unique scroll panes as for the other suggestion, to 'do some debugging' and 'Add System.out.println() statements' , that's what I've been doing for the last couple of days.  Very helpful.

Comment: `Very helpful` - your welcome.  `... that's what I've been doing for the last couple of days` - Where??? There are no System.out.println(...) statements in in your code!!! We have no idea what you have been doing to debug the code. The point of the suggestion is that if you create unique instances of the scroll pane and unique instances of the table, then you should have 13 unique components displayed. If you only have 1, that indicates you don't have 13 unique instances or you only add the last instance created to the scroll pane.

Comment: We are not here to read through hundreds of lines of code to try to understand your looping logic. The point of any development is to write a small amount of code and test, then add more code and test. When the code stops working you know where the problem is. Don't write the whole application before you start testing!